# Certificates, identifiers and profiles page not access in developer.apple

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, account

I am facing problem in apple developer account since three days certificates,identifiers and profiles page not open and gives an error message as below,

> Sorry,that page cannot be found. Try searching below or go to
>   developer.apple.com.

I am not able to create any certificates in apple developer account,Please give me solution to access certificates section.

[image: page not open and gives an error message]

Comment: contact apple support , no one else can help you quicker than the responsible authority

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan we drop mail to apple support waiting for response,hop so they will help us .

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar can you attach the screenshot of which screen is opening after login?

Comment: @techloverr attached , When I click on certificates,identifiers and profiles this page will open

Comment: One possibility can be removing your browser cookies and web cache . Then login again on developer.apple.com .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan great thank you ,it's working fine now I deleted all cookies and web cache.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer , It might be helpful for others in future facing the same problem. Accept that answer for clear visibility for others :)

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Yes sure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove your browser cookies and web cache . Then login again on developer.apple.com

Comment: If you are worried about your cookies and history just try it in another browser :)